# Which version of Insight toolkit is supported with visual studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, itk

I am building a project which refers to ITK. I am using visual studio 2013 compiler. Can someone please guide me with the lowest version of ITK compatible with visual studio 2013?

Answer (score 0):

[ITK version 4.5](https://itk.org/Wiki/ITK/Release_4.5) seems to be the first one with some support for Visual Studio 2013.